# How to create an array in an object after filtering and mapping it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object and there are some similarities with the type and  id. If the type and the id match, I would like to change content into an array and store all the relevent contents there.

I can’t seem to wrap my head around objects and mapping. Any help would greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
[{
type: 'movs',
id: '1001',
content: '111'
},
{
type: 'books',
id: '1001',
content: '222'
},
{
type: 'books',
id: '1001',
content: '333'
},
{
type: 'books',
id: '1002',
content: '444'
},
{
type: 'movs',
id: '1001',
content: '112'
},
{
type: 'movs',
id: '1005',
content: '113'
}]
```

to become

```
[{
type: 'movs',
id: '1001',
content: ['111', '112']
},
{
type: 'movs',
id: '1005',
content: ['113']
},
{
type: 'books',
id: '1001',
content: ['222', '333']
},
{
type: 'books',
id: '1002',
content: ['444']
}]
```

Edited: quotes

Comment: ^ By syntax, you just need to replace the `’` and `‘` with `'`.

Comment: This is not my homework. I am a ux designer mainly focused on adobe xd and principle. I am new to programming languages and am trying to learn javascript. Also, if there are any resources where I could learn more about objects, it would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @snowbird so you can read about `reduce` and learn how to do group by operation on array, and then try, if you still stuck just post the code you tried and people here are more than happy to help :)

Comment: sorry about the quotes. I typed them out in the text box and then added spaces at the front. i didn't notice it until it was pointed out

Comment: This will help you get some idea [`Most efficient way to do group by in JavaScript`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1):

Once you fix the invalid quotes, you just use `reduce`:

```js
const arr = [{type:"movs",id:"1001",content:"111"},{type:"books",id:"1001",content:"222"},{type:"books",id:"1001",content:"333"},{type:"books",id:"1002",content:"444"},{type:"movs",id:"1001",content:"112"},{type:"movs",id:"1005",content:"113"}];

const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((a, { type, content, id }) => (a[`${type}_${id}`] = (a[`${type}_${id}`] || { type, id, content: [] }), a[`${type}_${id}`].content.push(content), a), {}));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

More verbose/understandable version:

```js
const arr = [{type:"movs",id:"1001",content:"111"},{type:"books",id:"1001",content:"222"},{type:"books",id:"1001",content:"333"},{type:"books",id:"1002",content:"444"},{type:"movs",id:"1001",content:"112"},{type:"movs",id:"1005",content:"113"}];

const res = arr.reduce((accumulator, currentItem) => {
  let { type, id, content } = currentItem;
  let uniqueIdentifier = `${type}_${id}`; 
// { type, id, content: [] }), a[`${type}_${id}`].content.push(content), a), {}));
  if (accumulator[uniqueIdentifier]) {
    accumulator[uniqueIdentifier].content.push(content);
  }
  else {
    accumulator[uniqueIdentifier] = { type, id, content: [content] };
  }
  return accumulator;
}, {});

const resultArr = Object.values(res);

console.log(resultArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: I know @CodeManiac, just doing that now.

Comment: Fixed @CodeManiac